# Selecting font size in a table

Tags: tables, fontsize

I have the following table decleration:

```
\begin{table}[H] 
\caption{Tree construction table for subsample 1}
\centerline{
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 %%%%%VALUES%%%
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

However, I need to choose a size between \superscript and \tiny since the former is too large for my page while the latter is too small. How can this be done (selecting font size)

Comment: if you are not using the default cm fonts you can use `\fontsize{6pt}{7pt}\selectfont` or whatever size you want, but are there no other options, such as reducing the inter-column space (`\tabcolsep`) or removing teh vertical lines or ...

Answer (score 3):

Font size, with the New Font Selection System, can be selected in the following way:

```
\fontsize{size}{leading}\selectfont
```

where *size* is the point size you want (say, 10pt) and *leading* is the leading (space between lines) you want (say, 12pt).

This does, as mentioned, require scalable fonts, or at least font definition files which permit dynamic generation of the appropriately-sized bitmap fonts.  If you say `\usepackage{lmodern}` you'll get the fully-scalable Latin Modern fonts, which are near-duplicates of Computer Modern; if you really want to use Computer Modern, you can say `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` *before your `\documentclass` command* to get better font definition files for Computer Modern.

As David Carlisle says, though, shrinking your table to such small sizes to make it fit is generally a bad idea, as it impedes readability and clashes with your normal-size text.  Better options are reduce spacing between columns, or even setting the table in landscape mode on its own page; see the `lscape` package.

If you're not already using it, look at the `booktabs` package, as well, which makes tables created in LaTeX worlds better.